# Trying to rearrange a table in R. (I'm a beginner!) is there some sort of 'transpose' function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to rearrange a table in R.

I have (as an example) 52 individual lions. Each lion was measured for 92 different markers on blood samples taken during 4 time points. At the moment, I have a column for lion ID which is 208 rows long, as it is arranged next to the column 'sample number' which denotes the time point it was taken, time 1,2,3,4. Then there are the values from the blood sample from the 92 different markers. So 94 columns in total (ID, Sample number and Marker type).

See data:

```
'ID' 'Sample Number' 'Marker type'
-Lion 1 time 1 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92 
-Lion 1 time 2 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 1 time 3 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 1 time 4 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 2 time 1 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 2 time 2 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 2 time 3 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 2 time 4 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 3 time 1 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 3 time 2 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 3 time 3 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
-Lion 3 time 4 Marker 1 Marker 2 Marker 3...Marker 92
```

I need to change it so it gives me a column for the 52 lion IDs (rather than 4 rows per lion) then for each 92 markers, 4 columns for the sample number, giving 369 columns in total.

Expected Output data:

```
'ID' 'Sample Number' 'Marker type'    
 lion 1 time 1 marker 1 time 2 marker 1 time 3 marker 1 time 4 marker 1
 lion 2 time 1 marker 2 time 2 marker 2 time 3 marker 2 time 4 marker 2
 lion 3 time 1 marker 3 time 2 marker 3 time 3 marker 3 time 4 marker 3
```

I don't particularly want to make a new variable of time 1 marker 1, but rather a column for marker 1, split into 4 columns of time, with 1 row for lion. The same for marker 2 and so on.

Comment: Is this a `matrix` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide an actual (and much smaller) example dataset? I suggest something like 2-3 lions, 3 times each, with 4 markers, using distinct values for each; a general solution will work with 4 and 400 markers just as easily. Similarly, turn that (manually, with excel if need be) into your expected output given that input. And then include that in the question programmatically (`data.frame`) or with `dput(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can use `pivot_wider` here :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Samp_Num, values_from = Mark1:Mark3))
#OR
#tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Samp_Num, values_from = starts_with("Mark"))

# A tibble: 3 x 13
#  ID    Mark1_time1 Mark1_time2 Mark1_time3 Mark1_time4 Mark2_time1 Mark2_time2
#  <fct> <fct>       <fct>       <fct>       <fct>       <fct>       <fct>      
#1 Lion1 Marker1     Marker1     Marker1     Marker1     Marker2     Marker2    
#2 Lion2 Marker1     Marker1     Marker1     Marker1     Marker2     Marker2    
#3 Lion3 Marker1     Marker1     Marker1     Marker1     Marker2     Marker2    
# … with 6 more variables: Mark2_time3 <fct>, Mark2_time4 <fct>,
#   Mark3_time1 <fct>, Mark3_time2 <fct>, Mark3_time3 <fct>, Mark3_time4 <fct>
```

In my sample data we have 3 Mark columns and we now have 13 columns in final output (3 * 4 for each time + 1). Similarly, for your actual data you should have 369 columns (92 * 4 + 1).

**data**

Created a small sample data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Lion1", "Lion2", "Lion3"), class = "factor"), 
Samp_Num = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("time1", "time2", "time3", "time4"
), class = "factor"), Mark1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Marker1", class = "factor"), 
Mark2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Marker2", class = "factor"), Mark3 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Marker3", class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```